# css3 - @keyframe - animations: Reverse animation on mouse enter

Tags: html, css

I've been experimenting with the css3 animations and I'm struggling with the animation-direction property.

What I want to do is when the mouse enters the div, the div:hover is activated, causing the div animation to travel back the other direction.

I have the original animation on infinite loop, and when the mouse enters the div it (i guess) generates another div which travels in the reverse direction. This behavior also only occurs if I keep my mouse hovered over the opposite traveling div.

My mere human mind intuitively thinks that when I mouse enter the div, it will stop animating that direction and reverse.

Is it possible to do this? Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rweeber/7cByH/1/

```
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:purple;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:test;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}
div:hover
{
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:test;
    -webkit-animation-duration:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:reverse;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}
@keyframes test
{
    0%   {background: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background: blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    5%  {background: green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes test
{
    0%   {background: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background: blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background: green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background: red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find a way of doing this in a pure css way. Not least because of the general lack of support for `direction:reverse`, as even the supported implementations seem unable to change the direction once the animation has been initiated. Wow, that's pessimistic :/

Comment: You'll have to use javascript unless you want it to jump to the beginning each time